# Moving artboard from one document to another illustrator CS6

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6, artboard

I am trying to move an artboard from on document to another. I have move/copy artboard turned on and the layers are unlocked. I go to artboards in tool bar and select copy and then paste in new document but it only pastes the graphic. I've tried selecting artboard and dragging it up to document tab like you can do in photoshop but its not working either. This is what I have read to do when I searched.

https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/copy_move_artboards.html

Have followed this but it doesn't give the same results.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe *artboards* are inter-document transferable. At least not in CS6. You *absolutely* can't drag them to other documents (or tabs). They won't leave the boundaries of the document they reside in.

Just draw a rectangle the size of your artboard...

select it and the graphic
copy... paste into new document
 then select just the rectangle 
and convert it to an artboard via `Object > Artboards > Convert to Artboard`.